# How to enable different thousand separator and differend rounding for different kinds of numbers in the same document?

Tags: siunitx, numprint

How can I add different kinds of thousand separators and rounding to different kinds of numbers in the same document?
I want to set up that EURO amounts are displayed always rounded to two decimal points and with `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal point as this: `1.234,56 €`
All other numbers should use a small space `\,` as thousand separator (and still `.` as decimal point) and not round at all like: `1 234,567 89 g` or `12 345,678 9 m`

I tried with `siunitx` and `numprint` but both only were able to provide one setting for all numbers... and `numprint` also did not display the units correctly or in the font I selected.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[detect-all, locale=DE, separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {.}, group-minimum-digits = 4}

\begin{document}
    \SI{1234.5678}{€}
    
    \SI{1234.56789}{g}
    
    \SI{12345.6789}{m}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Ideally I would be able to set the thousand separator dependent on the language selected by `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` or `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Comment: Locally set `group-separator = {.<desired type>}` and `round-precision = ...` ?

Comment: What would that help if through the whole document at different positions are EUR values and other numbers...?

Comment: Do you test, what happens? I can't do this for you ....

Comment: Of course it works. That would mean manually switching between different group separators every time. Which would not be user-friendly... However, with your comment I now created a new command `\newcommand{\euro}[1]{
\sisetup{group-separator = {.}, round-precision = 2, round-mode = places}
\num{#1}\,€
\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, round-precision = 10, round-mode = figures}
}`which seems to work...

Comment: Are you willing and able to use a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set keys locally. I'd not use `\SI` for amounts of money, but `\num` followed by the currency symbol.

Also `\SI` should be `\qty`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{sourcesanspro}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  locale=DE,
  separate-uncertainty,
  output-decimal-marker={.},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EUR}{m}{%
  \num[
    group-minimum-digits=3,
    round-mode=places,
    group-separator={.},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
  ]{#1}\,€%
}

\begin{document}

\EUR{1234.5678}
    
\qty{1234.56789}{g}
    
\qty{12345.6789}{m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, I don't like Helvetica.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Much easier than the version I had come up with after the first comment. I will accept the answer even though you do not like Helvetica. ;-) Maybe I can have a look at sourcesanspro and also give it a chance. :-)

Comment: Would it be possible, though, to also make different definitions for different languages that will be autodetected from the `babel` variables?

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing and able to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, the following solution should be of interest to you. (The following test document will compile under pdfLaTeX as well, but it won't perform the special formatting you want to apply to amounts of euro-denominated currency.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, 
         locale = DE, 
         separate-uncertainty,  
         group-separator = {\,}, 
         output-decimal-marker = {,},
         group-minimum-digits = 4}

\usepackage{iftex} % for "\ifluatex" conditional
\ifluatex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}
\else
   \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
   \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\fi

\ifluatex
   \usepackage{luacode}
   \begin{luacode}
   function DoEuro ( s )
      -- take care to permit whitespace in the input string (with "%s-")
      s = s:gsub ("\\SI%s-%{%s-([%d%.]+)%s-%}%s-%{%s-€%s-%}",
                  "\\SI[group-separator={.}, round-precision=2, round-mode=places]{%1}{€}" )
      return s
   end
   \end{luacode}
   %% assign the "DoEuro" function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback:
   \AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
      "process_input_buffer" , DoEuro, "DoEuro" )}}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \SI{1234.5678}{€ }
    
    \SI  { 123456789.012345  }  {  € } 
    
    \medskip
    \SI{1234.56789}{g}
    
    \SI{12345.6789}{m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think I will not want to be limited to have to use lualatex... Or does this offer some very powerful functionalities?

Comment: @mrCarnivore - LuaLaTeX is, for the most part, a superset of pdfLaTeX. One particularly powerful additional functionality of LuaLaTeX is its direct access to Lua, the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of placeholders redefined with the help the mechanisms provided by `babel`:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[detect-all, locale=DE, separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-separator = {\thegroupmark},
  output-decimal-marker = {\thedecimalmark},
  group-minimum-digits = 4}

% The default values
\newcommand\thedecimalmark{,}
\newcommand\thegroupmark{\,}

% Reset at every language
\AddBabelHook{decimal}{afterextras}{%
  \renewcommand\thedecimalmark{,}%
  \renewcommand\thegroupmark{\,}}

% Set for a specific language (here english)
\AddBabelHook[english]{decimal}{afterextras}{%
  \renewcommand\thedecimalmark{.}%
  \renewcommand\thegroupmark{,}}

\begin{document}
\SI{1234.5678}{€}
    
\selectlanguage{english} \SI{1234.5678}{€}

\selectlanguage{ngerman} \SI{1234.5678}{€}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]